# Wordpress MU users - how are they organized?

Tags: multisite, users

WP and WP MU are a bit different, for example in users.

I'm not sure that I understand user functionality correctly.
Tell me please what are the differences between WP and WP MU users?

For example I know that MU-users register only once on the main site of a network (ie they shouldn't register on each subsite). Also I know that a user can eighter have or not have a subsite. And know that there is a possibility to add a user to a certain subsite. It seems that's all I know :)

Is it possible for user to register oneself on a certain subsite (but not only in the network in general) to be already automatically assigned to a certain subsite right after registration? How?
What is a possibility to add a user to a certain subsite for? Can I delete a user from a certain site?
And so on...

Comment: you are asking several questions maybe better to have a seperate question for each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conceptual difference between users in a standalone site and a network site is that in a network the users do not belong to the site but to the network itself are are being automatically logged in into all the network site once they login to one. Most of the time the difference can be ignored but there are some edge cases in which the differences come to like, like trying to make an anonymous comment when you are logged in to the network.

In a network you don't add users to a site but only to the network, then you give them permission to do some actions on the site they were registered for. In a standalone registration implies automatically some permissions.

This implies that as a subsite admin in a network you can not modify a user as it is not the sites user but the network's one. The most that can usually be done is to change the users permissions for that subsite.

Comment: Mark, thank you a lot, next time I'll separate questions. But now it's much more clear!